# HTTP response code: 400 for URL?

Tags: java, web-services, post

I am not able to request a POST service using Java. When I use curl on a terminal it works:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"blackoutDate":"2016/05/03", "blackoutTime":"18:45:36"}' http://poweranalyzer-skyglover.rhcloud.com/blackouts/
```

However, on my java program it does not work:

```
String uri = "http://poweranalyzer-skyglover.rhcloud.com/blackouts/";
        URL url = new URL(uri);
        StringBuffer params = new StringBuffer("");
        params.append("blackoutDate=" + URLEncoder.encode("2016/05/03", "UTF-8"));
        params.append("blackoutTime=" + URLEncoder.encode("18:45:36", "UTF-8"));

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(params.toString().length()));
        connection.connect();

        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        writer.write(params.toString());
        writer.flush();

        InputStream inputStream;
        if (connection.getResponseCode() == 201) {
            inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        } else {
            inputStream = connection.getErrorStream();
        }

        // Get the response
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println("-----" + line);
        }
        writer.close();
        rd.close();

        connection.disconnect();
```

I am getting:

> -----
>   -----400 Bad Request
>   -----
>
> ## Bad Request
>
> -----
>
> The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at my question once again I realized that content type should be **application/json**, and the way I send my parameters could change to a JSON form:

```
    String uri = "http://poweranalyzer-skyglover.rhcloud.com/blackouts/";
    URL url = new URL(uri);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

    String input = "{\"blackoutDate\":\"2016/05/03\", \"blackoutTime\":\"18:45:36\"}";

    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    os.write(input.getBytes());
    os.flush();

    if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + conn.getResponseCode());
    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (conn.getInputStream())));

    String output;
    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    conn.disconnect();
```

This solved my problem.